# Creating Bounding Box across an object in a video

Tags: python, opencv, find, contour, box

Opencv with Python!
I am trying to create  bounding boxes across objects in a video. I have already used the background subtraction function. I am using finContour function. Now the code detects the edges of the 'bus' in the video and creates a bounding box, but it also detects the edges of the windows of the bus and creates a bonding box for each of the window. I just need to get a bounding box across the bus only.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Python27\\clip1.avi")
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    # res,thresh = cv2.threshold(fgmask,127,255,0)
    kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(fgmask,kernel,iterations = 1)
    erosion = cv2.erode(fgmask,kernel,iterations = 1)
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for i in range(0, len(contours)):
        if (i % 1 == 0):
            cnt = contours[i]


            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            cv2.drawContours(fgmask ,contours, -1, (255,255,0), 3)
            cv2.rectangle(fgmask,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)



cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
cv2.imshow("original",frame)

if cv2.waitKey(30) == ord('a'):
    break
```

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

[image]
[image]

Comment: A quick trick could be putting certain threshold(s) for the area of the boxes and dropping the small ones.

Comment: loop over all bounding boxes and combine overlapped bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#img.png is the fgmask 
img=cv2.imread('img.png')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)


cv2.imshow('image1',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destoryAllWindows(0)
```

## RESULTS

[image]

Comment: I am able to get the big bounding box, But it looks somewhat like the edited pic. Even though I am dilating and eroding it, it isn't coming as expected!

Comment: ok you are saying that it is a bit shifted ?? right?? Ok BackgroundSubtractorMOG will return you an image where the parts in the image that are in motion will be in white so it will be a bit shifted to the direction its moving